# Sliding a tableview when keyboard shows up

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I am trying to slide a textbox, which is located in the bottom of a tableview (actually, in its footer view). So I tried two methods:

1. To animate autolayout constraint
2. Animate content insets of a tableview

Still, non of them worked, or partially worked. Currently, I am not able to test this on a real iPad (app is iPad only) and I am testing on Simulator, but I thought something like this should work:

1. Animating contentInsets

   ```
   func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
       if let keyboardHeight = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue.height {
           UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
               self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, keyboardHeight, 0)
           })
       }
   }

   func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
       UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
           self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
       })
   }
   ```
2. Animating autolayout constraint

   ```
   func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
       if let keyboardHeight = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue.height {
           UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
               self.bottomTableviewConstraint.constant = keyboardHeight
               self.qaTableview.layoutIfNeeded()
           })
       }
   }

   func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
       UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
           self.bottomTableviewConstraint.constant = 0
           self.qaTableview.layoutIfNeeded()
       })
   }
   ```

So in first example, I never noticed animation, nor tableview content moving. In the second example I made an outlet of a autolayout constraint (bottom vertical spacing) but I get some odd results. eg, tableview moves up, but not completely, and only for the first time.

If I put a breakpoint, `keyboardHeight` is equal to `471`. I am I missing something obvious ?

Comment: Use [IQKeyboardManager](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager#installation-with-cocoapod-)

Comment: @pkc456 Sorry, no 3rd party is an option for me.

Comment: Why can't you test on the simulator?

Comment: @Devster101 I said I am testing on Simulator ... ;)

Comment: Sorry I must have misread, when you say "Still, non of them worked, or partially worked." You can't test on a real iPad, just the simulator. Whats the difference? The simulator should be the same

Comment: Which type of animation you want????

Comment: @Swift_Guru A simple slide up / slide down animation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I tried and it worked perfectly fine as expected.

Can you check where you added your Notification center?

-- Animating contentInsets

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}

func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardHeight = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue.height {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
            self.tbl.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, keyboardHeight, 0)
        })
    }
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
        self.tbl.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
    })
}
```

-- Animating autolayout constraint

Make sure you do not have both Bottom layout and height constraints set for UITableView in Storyboard.

***NOTE***

But there's an even more easy way to do this, just by using a `UITableViewController`. It will take care of this feature by default. This is, of course, if you have no problem in using it.

***EDIT***

`UITextView` will act a little different from `UITextField`. Set `delegate` for `UITextView`. And do all table view alignments in `textViewShouldBeginEditing`.

```
extension ViewController: UITextViewDelegate {
    func textViewShouldBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) -> Bool {
        let pointInTable:CGPoint = textView.superview!.convert(textView.frame.origin, to: tbl)
        tbl.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: tbl.contentOffset.x, y: pointInTable.y)
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I will check as soon as I get my hands on computer but I would say I put observers in viewDidLoad, and removed them in deinit. Still, I am positive that those methods work because i checked by puting a breakpoint. And sadly, no TableViewController is an option here...

Comment: The odd thing is, I have tried this... And it works with `UITextField`. But I am using `UITextView` and it doesn't really work. I mean, it slides, not for the right amount. At least it looks like that.

Comment: You want UITextView in table footer view to scroll up?

Comment: I have a UITextView inside of a last cell. So I want whole tableview to be moved up while I am typing on a keyboard. I have a custom footer loaded from a nib if that matters (a simple view with one button).

Comment: It was actually a silly mistake inside of my custom header(s) ... I ended up changing contentOffset property on a tableview in keyboardWillShow/Hide methods.

Answer (score 0):

I use IQKeyboardManager library, which handles this behavior: https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

IQKeyboardManager allows you to prevent issues of the keyboard sliding up and cover UITextField/UITextView without needing you to enter any code and no additional setup required. To use IQKeyboardManager you simply need to add source files to your project.

It's really easy to implement. Import the library with pods, and just add, in your AppDelegate:

```
import IQKeyboardManager
```

And in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enable = true
```